# TablePagination Reactjs error KeyboardArrowRight

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When I try to use the material-ui pagination object I'm getting 
[the error from the linked image][1]

react-dom.development.js:19560 The above error occurred in the  component:
    in /node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/internal/svg-icons/KeyboardArrowRight.js
    in span (created by ForwardRef)
    in button (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef) (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef) (created by ForwardRef)
    in div (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by ForwardRef)
    in div (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef) (created by ForwardRef)
    in td (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef) (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef)
    in div (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef)
    in header
    in div
    in main (created by r)
    in div (created by t)
    in div (created by t)
    in t (created by r)
    in div (created by r)
    in div (created by r)
    in r (created by x)
    in x
    in Unknown (created by Context.Consumer)
    in t (created by h)
    in h
    in div
    in Unknown (created by r)
    in t (created by r)
    in Suspense (created by r)
    in r (created by x)
    in x (created by r)
    in r
    in e
    in t (created by n)
    in n (created by Context.Consumer)
    in i (created by x)
    in x
    in t
    in s

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to uninstall @material-ui/core using following command (using npm or yarn):

```
// with npm
npm uninstall @material-ui/core

// with yarn
yarn remove @material-ui/core
```

and then install @material-ui/core again using following command:

```
// with npm
npm install @material-ui/core

// with yarn
yarn add @material-ui/core
```